# Compile function from string on-the-fly in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, on-the-fly

I'm working on a silly project in python that effectively implements a semi-REPL in a web-browser, and I'm stuck on how to cleanly dynamically evaluate code on-the-fly.

Basically, I have a web-form where the user enters a function, which should be then executed on the server.

The expected entry is a single function, with defined parameters. The function name, however, is not specified.

What I want is to get a string, such as:

```
def function_for_xxx(param_1, param_2, param_3):
    <stuff goes here>
    return interesting_value
```

and somehow convert that into a normal python function object (e.g. object of type `<class 'function'>`).

I can limit the scope of the task somewhat:

- The user is *explicitly* trusted, so I don't have to worry about sanitization.
- There are a few environment functions that should be passed into the function globals, but I can explicitly specify them.
- Enforcing the string being a single bare function is actually desireable.

Right now, I've experimented a bit with the `compile()` and `exec()` calls, but they appear to insert the `exec()`ed code into the current local scope, which is non ideal. I'd really like the exec to be done without side effects like that, and just return a module or the bare function.

Comment: Why can't you save it as a .py file and execute it?

Comment: @MotKohn - That just moves the problem around. Then I'd be having to load modules on the fly. And it's a lot less elegant. And I have a *LOT* of these functions that can all be changed independently (several hundreds to a few thousands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a workaround that is kind of hackish, but does what I want.

Basically, we can exploit the fact that we can specify the execution scope to `exec()` calls by specifying the `globals` parameter.

```
func_container = compile(func"\n", "<dynamic_functions_xxx>", "exec")

scope = {
    <objects made available to the dynamic function>
}
exec(func_container, scope)
```

Objects defined in the `func` string are now present in the `scope` variable, with no side effects to the local namespace.

General comments apply here. If you can memoize the compile/exec process, doing so is probably a good idea (compiling is slow!).